# pick last item of repeated list in rxjs

Tags: javascript, sockets, merge, rxjs, distinct

I am getting a bunch of streams from a Socket and want to pick the latest item.

I know `distinctUntilChanged` is picking the first item, but I need to reverse this functionality somehow.

In summary I want do this by rxjs:

```
In:  1 - 1 - 1 - 2 - 2 - 3 - 3 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 2 - 2 - 2 - 1 - 2 - 2 - 3 - 3
Out: - - - - 1 - - - 2 - - - 3 - - - - - 1 - - - - - 2 - 1 - - - 2 - 3 - -
```

Comment: I think your expected out is ambiguous. You cannot know a input is last input of one identical value series. I can know it when other value comes. For example, in case of `1 - 1 - 1 - 2`, you can know third `1` is last input of `1`s when `2` comes. So, is it your expected output to get `1` when `2` comes?

Answer (score 0):

We can emit last value after it was changed:

```
In:  1 - 1 - 1 - 2 - 2 - 3 - 3 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 2 - 2 - 2 - 1 - 2 - 2 - 3 - 3
Out: - - - - - - 1 - - - 2 - - - 3 - - - - - 1 - - - - - 2 - 1 - - - 2 - 3

import { pairwise, take, filter, map, merge, last } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { interval, from } from 'rxjs';

const stream$ = from([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]);

stream$
  .pipe(
    pairwise(),
    filter(([prev, cur]) => prev !== cur),
    map(([prev, cur]) => prev),
    merge(stream$.pipe(last()))
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```